# Display total amount from ajax action page to in ajax calling page separate from the ajax output table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How do I display the total amount from sales table in the below of ajax return output table then how it pass and accept in calling page?

**ajax action page**

```
$customer=$_POST["from_date"];
  $item=$_POST["to_date"];
  $quantity=$_POST["qty"];
  $ins=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO sale(pr_id,customer_name,item,quantity,sale_date) VALUES ('$item','$customer','$item','$quantity','$date')");
  $query="SELECT p.pr_name,  p.mrp, s.quantity,s.customer_name FROM sale s JOIN product p ON ( s.pr_id = p.pr_id ) WHERE s.customer_name = '$customer' AND p.pr_id = '$item'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $output = '';  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  $i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       { 
            $output .= '  
                 <tr> 
                      <td>'.$i.'</td> 
                      <td>'. $row["pr_name"] .'</td> 
                      <td>'. $row["quantity"] .'</td> 
                      <td>'. $row["mrp"] .'</td>  
                 </tr>  
            ';  
              $output .= '  

            ';  
$i++;
       }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  

  $output .= ' <tr> 
  <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
  <td>'. $row["pr_name"] .'</td> 
  <td>'. $row["quantity"] .'</td>
  <td>'. $row["mrp"] .'</td> 
  </tr>    
  ';  
  echo $output;  
}  
?>
```

Comment: You mean `$.get("actionpage.php",{"from_date":fromdate,"to_date":todate, "qty":quantity},function(data) { $("table>tbody").append(data) });`

Comment: *"I want"* does not explain a problem. What problem are you having achieving your goal and what is the question? Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl - English is obviously not OPs first language

Comment: actually i have fetched total using query, now i want to pass it into the ajax calling page.and display there

Comment: in the above code there is displaying a table now i want to display total below that table

Comment: You can add a row with the total value. You'll need to calculate that total value before in the while loop. What I don't understand is the last **$output .=**  assign, is it duplicating the last row?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript part of this question other than inserting the returned rows into a table??

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through all table cells with the total for each row? First, give the cell a class we can refer to (e.g. totalbox)

In jQuery:

```
var total = 0;
$('.totalbox').each(function(){
    boxTotal = $(this).html();    
    total = total + boxTotal;
});
$('#some-other-div').html(total);
```

You might need to parse the val into a number, it may well probably be treated as a string.